# iOS app gives errors if it goes to the background & comes back"nw_read_request_report [C3]Receive failed with error"Software caused connection abort"

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, runtime-error, swift5

The issue on the app is that once the user goes to the background and comes back to the app, it gives a few errors like in the attached image.

[image]

These errors do arise when the user clicks on a push notification as well.

Tried changing and removing pods, their versions and everything but nothing seems to be working. This happens when I run the app on the physical device and not on the simulator.

Hope you guys could help me on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is related with network requests that are killed during backgrounding. Similar problem was described in [Alamofire issues](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/3227).

Comment: I went through it and I don't seem to have an idea on how to solve this. If you have any sort of idea on it, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: I just check it and the same error appears for a clean project. Did you get something like that ```Can't end BackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 1 (0x1), or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.``` ? Because then you can also add breakpoint for that `UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError` symbol and maybe somehow it will help you.